# Is there a hydrophobic gas?

Tags: water, gas-laws

I am looking into the subject of water repelling and have been led to the hydrophobic subject area. I have two questions regarding this subject.

1. Is there a hydrophobic gas ?
2. If a hydrophobic liquid is heated to a gas does it loose its water repellent qualities.

Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 8):

The trouble with the question is that hydrophobicity is not a meaningful concept in a gas.

The concept is mostly useful when characterising how surfaces behave. Typical hydrophobic compounds don't interact strongly with water (e.g. non polar hydrocarbon waxes) and tend to disrupt water's hydrogen bond network. So water doesn't "wet" the surface and tends to form droplets that seem to be trying to minimise the contact area with the surface. The contact angle that a droplet makes with the surface is used as a measure of static hydrophobicity (if the droplet spreads out because the surface likes to interact with water, the angle is low, if the surface reels water the angle is high).

It is less clear that describing liquid phases as hydrophobic is meaningful, though it is not uncommon in casual usage. Compounds that would be hydrophobic as solids will probably exist as liquids that don't mix with water or can form micelles where they cluster together in very small droplets in the water phase. The bulk effect that matters is that hydrophobic compounds don't mix with water and form separate phases. The hydrophobicity of the molecules describes why the separation happens, but the effect is immiscibility.

None of this matters in the gas phase. The point of gases (compared to solids or liquids) is that the bulk properties are not determined by molecular interactions. The molecules of a gas don't interact much and are, to a good approximation, interchangeable whatever the individual molecules are made of. Gas equations describing gas behaviour can effectively ignore the molecular interactions.

What this means is that if you take a compound that would be hydrophobic as a solid and immiscible with water as a liquid, it will mix quite happily with water vapour. So a hydrophobic compound can be a gas, but a gas can't be hydrophobic.

Comment: Nice answer! Just out of curiosity: if you look at droplets in the [Cassie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superhydrophobe) state, suspended on top of pillars with air in between, they get a higher contact angle than when they are purely in contact with the solid. This is (at least in an averaging sense) explained by the contact angle of water with the air between the pillars which is taken to be 180 degrees. Wouldn't that warrant the use of the term hydrophobic gas? Or would you argue that any gas is hydrophobic in this sense, thus making the term hydrophobic redundant?

Comment: @Michiel The *structure* of the surface (that is, its physical not chemical makeup) makes a lot of difference (so the Lotus leaf is more hydrophobic than the chemicals it is made from). So i still wouldn't use the term *hydrophobic gas* but stick to descriptions based on chemistry and structure of the surface.

Answer (score 4):

Sure many gases are hydrophobic! A hydrophobic molecule is in fact mainly a non polar molecule. So every non polar gas without $H$ bond site is a hydrophobic molecule. The alkanes for example are all hydrophobic molecules.

[image]

So in fact I will not say that if a hydrophobic liquid is heated to a gas  it loses its water repellent qualities, because in fact it is still a non polar molecule even if he has greater kinetic energy however in gas state molecules have a really low interaction between each other so it doesn't really have a strong influence in what happen if the polarity is different. For this reason I don't know if is really useful to speak of hydrophobic gas (even if someone use it see e.g. [The interface between water and a hydrophobic gas](http://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2008/CP/B801220B#!divAbstract)) because you can't measure contact angle or use other tests usually perform to characterize hydrophobic materials.

Comment: a hydrophobic compound can be a gas, but is the gas therefore hydrophobic? Is the concept even meaningful in a gas?

Comment: @matt_black I fully agree, I think the same but indeed the term hydrophobic gas is accepted so why don't write what gases can be called so?

Comment: is the term *hydrophobic gas* accepted? I'd like to see an example and an explanation of what the term could possibly mean.

Comment: @matt_black In fact is not so common however see the link I've posted or [this](http://books.google.it/books?id=jWs_AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA119&dq=hydrophobic+gas&hl=it&sa=X&ei=Y4naUrDgOKGGywO684LwAQ&ved=0CFEQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=hydrophobic%20gas&f=false) book!

Comment: A careful reading of the paper shows that the term "hydrophobic gas" only occurs in the context of a solid electrode *coating* on an electrode used in a system where a gas is one of the reactants. In context, the term refers to a *solid* hydrophobic layer on the surface of an electrode.

Comment: You are right for an example see the link in my answer, I will edit the question I thought was more common..

Answer (score 1):

Consider some zero dipole moment, "obviously" hydrophobic gases:  $\ce{CH4}$, $\ce{Xe}$, $\ce{SF6}$.  All three readily form water clathrate hydrates,

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clathrate_hydrate